# Oracle Stored Procedure benchmarking

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I am a .Net web developer working with a legacy Oracle database.  In the past I have worked with orm tools like nHibernate but all database communication here is required to be done via stored procedures.  Our dba is asking us to pass a bunch of administrative info to every procedure we call including the username/domain/ip of the end user.  This data is then used to call another stored procedure that logs usage info each time a procedure is called.

I am not that well versed in Oracle or Pl/Sql and I am trying to write my .Net code in a clean way that meets best practices whenever possible.  It seems to me that this process of passing extra data through to every procedure is messy and tedious on both the .Net and Oracle ends.

Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish the dba's goal without all the overhead?  Or is this a standard way of doing things that I should get used to.

Comment: It is definitely not standard and definitely doesn't seem to be a good way to do it. What kind of "extra" data are you required to pass (i.e. username, etc)?

Comment: yes we need to pass username, domain, ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a context rather than passing additional parameters to every stored procedure call.  A context is a convenient place to store arbitrary session-level state data that the stored procedures can all reference.

For example, I can create a context `MYAPP_CTX` for my application and create a simple package that lets me set whatever values I want in the context.

```
SQL> create context myapp_ctx using ctx_pkg;

Context created.

SQL> create package ctx_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure set_value( p_key in varchar2, p_value in varchar2 );
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create package body ctx_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure set_value( p_key in varchar2, p_value in varchar2 )
  4    as
  5    begin
  6      dbms_session.set_context( 'MYAPP_CTX', p_key, p_value );
  7    end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Package body created.
```

When the application gets a connection from the connection pool, it would simply set all the context information once.

```
SQL> begin
  2    ctx_pkg.set_value( 'USERNAME', 'JCAVE' );
  3    ctx_pkg.set_value( 'IP_ADDRESS', '192.168.17.34' );
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Subsequent calls and queries in the same session can then just ask for whatever values are stored in the context.

```
SQL> select sys_context( 'MYAPP_CTX', 'USERNAME' )
  2    from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('MYAPP_CTX','USERNAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JCAVE
```

Realistically, you'd almost certainly want to add a `clear_context` procedure to the package that called `dbms_session.clear_context( 'MYAPP_CTX' )` to clear whatever values had been set in the context when a connection was returned to the connection pool to avoid inadvertently allowing context information from one session to bleed over into another.  You would probably also design the package with separate procedures to set and to get at least the common keys (username, ip address, etc.) rather than having 'USERNAME' hard-coded multiple places.  I used a single generic `set_value` method just for simplicity.

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems there could be potential concurrency issues if multiple users were accessing sessions at the same time.  For example, what happens if a second user session sets the username/ip and then, the first user session calls a stored procedure that asks for the username.  Will it not return the username set by the second session?

Comment: @zaq - A context is (by default) local to a database session.  Only one user can be using a database session at a time (though multiple middle tier sessions might share a database session over time when they retrieve connections from the connection pool).  That's why you'd generally clear the context when a connection was returned to the connection pool, when the connection was pulled from the connection pool, or both.  Two database sessions will have separate copies of the data in their respective contexts-- one session won't see the information in the other session's context.